# How do I make the user be able to press enter in an Entry box Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my program:

[image]

I am having trouble making the user press enter so the program can actually trigger itself. I quite new to `tkinter`!

Here is the code for the Comboboxs:

```
self.measurements = StringVar()
self.Combobox_Length_Left = ttk.Combobox(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.measurements, values = ('mm', 'cm', 'inches', 'feet', 'yards', 'meter', 'km', 'miles'), width = 10)
self.Combobox_Length_Left.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

self.measurements1 = StringVar()
self.Combobox_Length_Right = ttk.Combobox(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.measurements1, value = ('mm', 'cm', 'inches', 'feet', 'yards', 'meter', 'km', 'miles'), width = 10)
self.Combobox_Length_Right.grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)
```

Here is the code for Entry boxes:

```
self.Text_Length_Left = IntVar()
self.Entry_Length_Left = ttk.Entry(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.Text_Length_Left,width = 13)
self.Entry_Length_Left.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

self.Text_Length_Right = IntVar()
self.Entry_Length_Right = ttk.Entry(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.Text_Length_Right,width = 13)
self.Entry_Length_Right.grid(row = 3, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
```

The code for the conversion of meters to ...:

```
as_meter = dict(mm=0.001, cm=0.01, inches=0.0254,feet=0.3048, yards=0.9144, meter=1.0,km=1000.0, miles=1609.344)
def update_length(self, *args):
    self.measurements.trace('w', self.update_length)
    self.measurements1.trace('w', self.update_length)
    self.Text_Length_Left.trace('w', self.update_length)
    try:
        v = float(self.Text_Length_Left.get())
    except ValueError:
        v = 0.0
        self.Text_Length_Left.set(str(v))
    m = v * self.as_meter[self.measurements.get()]
    r = m/self.as_meter[self.measurements1.get()]
    self.Text_Length_Right.set("{:.3e}".format(r))
```

I want to be able to press enter and the program will do its magic and for it to display the calculation in the other entry box and also the same procedure with the other entry box.

Thanks for any help! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looking to [`bind`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/binding-levels.html) the Enter key ([called `"<Return>"`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-types.html) by tkinter):

```
self.Combobox_Length_Right.bind("<Return>",self. update_length)
self.Combobox_Length_Right.bind("<Return>",self. update_length)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it coming up with the error:
`AttributeError: 'IntVar' object has no attribute 'bind'`

Comment: sorry, I meant `self.Combobox_Length_Right` will edit anwer

Comment: Thank you so much man you just helped me finish my project I have been working on for four months now I can't thank you enough.

Comment: I had to use `self.Entry_Length_Right.bind("<Return>",self. update_length)
        self.Entry_Length_Left.bind("<Return>",self. update_length)              ` to get it to work